# Format function not working in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba. i am trying to convert current date format to mm/dd/yyyy. I used format function to achieve it. Still i am getting as dd-mm-yyyy format.
 Dim current as Date

```
currentDate = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Date values are date values - formatting is irrelevant. If you simply output the value of currentDate to the immediate window it will be formatted according to your regional settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because *Format()* returns a **String:**

```
Sub NeedADate()
    Dim s As String
    s = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

First paste the desired date in a cell, then format the cell layout.

```
Cells(1,1).Value = Now()
Cells(1,1).Numberformat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```